# Explain Output in For loop C program

Tags: c, for-loop, output

Output explaination

```
for(i=5;++i;i-=3)
```

How does this for loop give output 642 can someone tell me how this works and how does the loop terminate if there is no condition?

Comment: debug it, may be it is time for you to brush up your programming skills..

Comment: (a) it doesn't _output_ anything; (b) your loop is incomplete; (c) there _is_ a termination condition: `++i`.

Comment: Values are something like this: 5, `6`, 3, `4`, 1, `2`, -1, `0`. Here it should stop. All this if i is signed. Values in grey are the one checked actually before for loop ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition here is implicit.
C considers as true **every integer not null**.

the ++i syntax is applied *before* the condition is evaluated
Therefore the program run as follows:

- start:
  i=5
- first loop

condition (`++i`)     =>     `i=6`

- second loop

iteration operation (`i-=3`) => `i=3`

condition (`++i`)     =>     `i=4`

i is evaluated to `true`

- third loop

iteration operation (`i-=3`) => `i=1`

condition (`++i`)     =>     `i=2`

i is evaluated to `true`

- *"fourth loop"*

iteration operation (`i-=3`) => `i=-1`

condition (`++i`)     =>     `i=0`

i is evaluated to `false`

- end

Answer (score 1):

The loop terminates when the *expression* `++i` - which is the condition check - equals zero. Note that the evaluation of the condition check happens before the loop body is ran, and there is a side effect of increasing `i` by 1.

You might find the `for` loop simpler to read if you rewrite it

```
for(i = 5; ++i;){
    // Here, observing i yields 6, 4, and 2.
    i -= 3;
}
```

Then you can see that `i` is, in sequence, 5, 6 (condition check side effect), 3 (decrement by 3), 4, 1, 2, -1, 0.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i;
 for(i=5;++i;i=0)
 {
 printf("%d",i);
 }}
So the output should be 563412-10 why is it only 642

Comment: No it shouldn't. It should be as I say in my comment in my code snippet. See for yourself with a line by line debugger.

Comment: printf only prints values you assign to. This is done only in for loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the three parts in your for-loop conceptually as:

```
i = 5;         /* first_expression */
while( ++i )   /* while( second_expression )*/
{
    /* for-loop body runs here */

    i -= 3;    /* third_expression */
}
```

The loop terminates when `++i` no longer evaluates to "true" (non-zero).  You could write exactly the same thing as `++i != 0`.